# Have or made a scoop of ice cream?

Tags: grammar, verbs

Let's say your were eating a delicious ice cream at your house. Initally, you had 3 scoops of ice cream and you put them into a cup and ate them all. Then, because of the mouthwatering taste of ice cream, you unwittingly **made/had** another round and you say:

> "What the... did I just **made** another scoop of ice cream?"

Or

> "What the... did I just **have** another scoop of ice cream?"

It has been a confusing thing about this 'made' usage, but my answer here is **made**. Still, I doubt it, shed some light guys, thx.

Comment: "Did I just make another scoop of ice cream" - sounds like you can make ice cream on your own.

"Did I just have another scoop of ice cream" - sounds like you ate another scoop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Had** is the correct word. Making would imply you are *actually taking the cream and flavor and churning it.* **Had** means you consumed it, or possessed it.

Ex:

> I had a nice dish of ice cream

Vs.

> I made myself homemade ice cream, then had a scoop of it.